# 'clear A of B' and 'clear B from A'

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

This is from [a news article](https://edition.cnn.com/2023/06/12/us/philadelphia-i95-collapse-fire-monday/index.html) :

> Crews worked through the night to **clear** the collapsed section
> **of** the road.
>
> Officials warned residents to avoid the area and to expect delays of
> trash collection and bus routes in the area.

[image]

I think that 'clear the collapsed section **from** the road' is correct if that sentence is describing the situation in the above photo.

Am I wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are clearing a collapsed section that *belongs to* a road, so it is a collapsed section *of* the road.  The collapsed section is a section of the road that is going from left to right in the photo.

You are correct that they are also clearing it from a road, but using the word *from* here would make the sentence a little less clear; when we hear "the collapsed section", [we almost always expect the word *of* to come next](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=section%20*&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3), because "a section" isn't really something that exists in isolation: it's a section *of* something else.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: The picture shows two roads, so they are clearing the collapsed section **of** the upper road **from** the lower road.

Comment: @PeterJennings Thank you very much.